# Close vote reasons on Meta are too low-contrast

Tags: bug, design, meta

Here’s a screenshot of close vote panels on both the Meta and Main sites:

[image]

The subtitle is an unnecessarily light grey, and hard to read against the white. I’d suggest changing it to the same dark grey used on the main site.